# How do I prevent the original field resuming focus when the dialog closes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

My users don't want to have to let go of the keyboard to use the mouse on an input form; so I need to use the onFocus event to show a JQuery UI Dialog to them. But, when calling the dialog's `close();` the dialog is being re-opened as the original field resumes focus. I've tried explicitly calling `focus()` on the next input field, but that call is ignored.

How do I prevent the original field resuming focus when the dialog closes?
Using `IE11`:

```
 $("#divPayorTypes").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 275,
        width: 465,
        top: 925,
        left: 275,
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        title: "Payor Type Options",
        buttons: [{
            text: "Set New Payor Type",
            click: function () {
                var payorType = $("#ddlPayorTypes :selected").text();
                var payorTypeId = $("#ddlPayorTypes").val();
                $("#CCTMainForEdit_PayorType").val(payorType);
                sessionStorage.setItem("CurrPayorType", payorType);
                $("#CCTMainForEdit_refPayorTypeID").val(payorTypeId);
                $("#CCTMainForEdit_CheckNmbr").focus();
                $("#divPayorTypes").dialog("close");
            }
         }, {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function () {
                $("#CCTMainForEdit_LastName").focus();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Have you tied switch the focus() and the dialog("close) functions? It maybe the order in which they are called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.blur()` on your focused field

Example:

```
$("#myInputID").blur();
```